# Create Terraform aws_subent from yaml

Tags: yaml, terraform

I want to generate a terraform config from yaml shown below that sets me the keys el2-dev and el2-shared-dev as a tag and sets the values of the lists public_subnets and private_subnets as cidr_block respectively.

```
aws:
  el2-dev:
    public_subnets:
      - "10.44.1.0/27"
      - "10.44.2.32/27"
      - "10.44.3.64/27"
    private_subnets:
      - "10.44.4.96/27"
      - "10.44.5.128/27"
      - "10.44.6.160/27"
  el2-shared-dev:
    public_subnets:
      - "10.44.7.0/27"
      - "10.44.8.32/27"
      - "10.44.9.64/27"
    private_subnets:
      - "10.44.10.96/27"
      - "10.44.11.128/27"
      - "10.44.12.160/27"
```

I was playing with this approach without a valid result.

```
locals {
  accounts = flatten([
    for profile_name, blocks in var.aws : [
      for record in blocks : {
        record = record
        profile_name   = profile_name
      }
    ]
  ])

}


resource "aws_subnet" "main" {
  for_each = { for entry in local.accounts : sort(entry.profile_name) => entry }

  cidr_block = tolist(local.cidr_blocks)

  vpc_id     = aws_vpc.main.id
  tags = {
    Name = flatten([each.value.record])
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Find a solution as followed:

**vpc.tf**

```
locals {
  subnets = flatten([
    for a in var.aws : [
      for ps in a.private_subnets : {
        accounts = a.accounts
        private_subnets    = ps
      }
    ]
  ])
}

resource "aws_vpc" "main" {
  cidr_block = var.vpc.cidr

}

resource "aws_subnet" "main" {
  for_each = {
    for cidr_block in local.subnets : cidr_block.private_subnets => cidr_block
  }

  cidr_block = each.value.private_subnets
  vpc_id     = aws_vpc.main.id
  tags = {
    Name = each.value.accounts
  }
}
```

**variables.tf**

```
variable "aws" {
  type = list(object({
    accounts = string
    public_subnets: list(string)
    private_subnets: list(string)
  }))
}
```

**settings.yaml**

```
aws:
  - accounts: el2-dev
    public_subnets:
      - "10.44.1.0/27"
      - "10.44.2.32/27"
      - "10.44.3.64/27"
    private_subnets:
      - "10.44.4.96/27"
      - "10.44.5.128/27"
      - "10.44.6.160/27"
  - accounts: el2-shared-dev
    public_subnets:
      - "10.44.7.0/27"
      - "10.44.8.32/27"
      - "10.44.9.64/27"
    private_subnets:
      - "10.44.10.96/27"
      - "10.44.11.128/27"
      - "10.44.12.160/27"
```